# How to target specific line of text within text-widget in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this html:

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area col-md-4" 
role="complementary">
<div id="text-3" class="widget widget_text">             
<div class="textwidget"><p><strong>Sign In</strong>. 
</p>
<p><strong>Create Account</strong></p>
<p><strong>Find your next employee on Adsler
</strong></p>
</div>
</div></aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

I want to target `Find your next employee on Adsler`

Tried.

```
.textwidget:nth-of-type (3) {font-size: 30px}
```

Nothing. Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this is using javascript or jQuery

```
<script>
$( ".textwidget:contains('Find your next employee on Adsler')" ).css( {fontSize: "50px"} );
<script>
```

This script will find all the strings 'Find your next employee on Adsler' under specified class/id.

You can add the script directly in the js file or add this jquery code by downloading a plugin naming as "simple custom css & js"

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks. But where would i put it? Can i put it in the additional css box in wordpress, or frame it within css?

Comment: Or somewhere in the plugin but where?

Comment: This is a jQuery code. Where you have placed it ? @user11364702

Comment: I placed it in the plugin you mentioned. I've found a way of doing it though, in a text widget in the sidebar using html. I'll answer the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Place a `text widget` in the sidebar on the page and place the following html in it.

```
<span style="font-size: large;">Foobar</span>
```